# How to apply same id as parent to children array in the same level?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, logic

I have the following object

```
[
    { name: "parent", id: 1 },
    { name: "children", id: 2 },
    { name: "children", id: 3 },
    { name: "parent", id: 4 },
    { name: "children", id: 5 }
]
```

As you can see, parent and children are all at the same level. What I need to do is to connect the children with the parent, applying the parent id to the children arrays with a new attribute. Something like this:

```
[
    { name: "parent", id: 1 },
    { name: "children", id: 2, parentId: 1 },
    { name: "children", id: 3, parentId: 1 },
    { name: "parent", id: 4 },
    { name: "children", id: 5, parentId: 4 },
    { name: "children", id: 6, parentId: 4 }
]
```

So far, I hadn't been able to achieve the logic for this issue. Any help on this matter will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you have only one level? what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop over your array and store the last encontered parent id, to be able to apply it to each subsequent child

```js
const data = [
    { name: "parent", id: 1 },
    { name: "children", id: 2 },
    { name: "children", id: 3 },
    { name: "parent", id: 4 },
    { name: "children", id: 5 }
]

let lastParentId = null
data.forEach(el => {
  if (el.name === "parent") {
    lastParentId = el.id
  } else {
    el.parentId = lastParentId
  }
})

console.log(data)
```

Comment: The answers are all just fine, but this one got here first. Thanks to everyone! It worked!

Comment: @JosePeres You can still upvote the other answers if you want to show appreciation to those who offered solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a reusable solution using map:

```js
const data = [{ name: "parent", id: 1 }, { name: "children", id: 2 }, { name: "children", id: 3 }, { name: "parent", id: 4 }, { name: "children", id: 5 }]

function map(data) {
  let lastId
  return data.map(e => {
    if (e.name === "parent") lastId = e.id
    if (e.name === "children") e.parentId = lastId
    return e
  })
}

console.info(map(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate the `array`, store the `parent id` of item with `name` equal to `parent`, set the children property of `parent id`

```js
const test = [
        { name: "parent", id: 1 },
        { name: "children", id: 2 },
        { name: "children", id: 3 },
        { name: "parent", id: 4 },
        { name: "children", id: 5 }
    ];

    let parentId = null; 
    for(let i = 0; i < test.length; i++){
        if(test[i].name === "parent") { 
            parentId = test[i].id; 
        } else { 
            test[i].parentid = parentId; 
        }    
    }
    
    console.log(test);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could store `parentId` from the last parent and map new object with this properity or the object without.

```js
const
    data = [{ name: "parent", id: 1 }, { name: "children", id: 2 }, { name: "children", id: 3 }, { name: "parent", id: 4 }, { name: "children", id: 5 }],
    result = data.map((parentId => o => {
        if (o.name === 'parent') {
            parentId = o.id;
            return o;
        }        
        return { ...o, parentId };
    })());

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the data using `Array.map` and check if the `name` in the object is `parent` if so, store the id in a variable return the same object. Otherwise, add the id stored to the object as `parentId`

```js
let data = [{name:"parent",id:1},{name:"children",id:2},{name:"children",id:3},{name:"parent",id:4},{name:"children",id:5}]

const processData = (data) => {
  let parentId = "";
  return data.map(d => {
    if(d.name === "parent") {
      parentId = d.id;
    } else {
      d.parentId = parentId
    }
    return d;
  })
}

console.log(processData(data))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```